# Find $k$ that will make $a^2-kN=b$ to be divisible by $p_1,p_2...p_s$ for some $a$

Tags: factoring, quadratic-residues

$$a^2-kN=b$$

Where $N$ is a positive big integer and $a,k,b$ are integers, not necessarily big or positive.

How to compute a $k$ that will make the primes $p_1,p_2...p_s$ to be a quadratic residue mod $kN$?

I need this to optimize the prime base in the quadratic sieve algorithm when factoring small numbers. It's beneficial to have many small primes in the factor base.

Comment: I assume that $N$ is a given positive integer and so are the primes $p_i$. If so please add this in question. Also you may want to give a little motivation about this problem and any specific thoughts you have about the solution.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh tnx, I updated the question.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but if $p_i$ is a quadratic residue $\mod kN$ then $p_i$ already is a quadratic residue $\mod N$, so multiplication of $N$ by $k$ will not make more of $p_i$ quadratic residues.

Comment: @AlexRavsky oh I didn't know that. Can you please show me proof that if $p_i$ is a quadratic residue $\mod kN$ then it also a quadratic residue $\mod N$

Comment: When $p_i$ is a quadratic residue $\mod kN$ then there exists an integer $x$ such that $kN|(x^2-p_i)$. So $N|(x^2-p_i)$, that is 
$p_i$ is a quadratic residue $\mod N$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky oh wow, so simple. Thank you!